# Failed to insert data into the table of mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

When I try to insert the data into mysql,also create a table in the db "db_of_lj",some error occurs but I do not know the reason.
Also, I try to print(cursor.description) but the output is "None".
I hope you can help me,thanks!

```
import pymysql
def create_city_table(city):
#create table
    global cursor
    cursor.execute("drop table if exists %s" % (city))
    create_table="create table %s(id int(10) not null primary key auto_increment," \
                 "total_price int(10)," \
                 "unitPrice int(10)," \
                 "room_desc varchar(20)," \
                 "construction_year int(10)," \
                 "area float," \
                 "location varchar(20));"
    try:
        cursor.execute(create_table % (city))
    except :
        print("Failed to create that table!")
        return None
    print("Successfully create table of '%s' in sql_db!" % city)

#connect to mysql
connect=pymysql.Connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3306,
    user="root",
    password="1111",
    db="db_of_lj"
)

#set a cursor
cursor = connect.cursor()
create_city_table("hangzhou")
insert2db = "insert into hangzhou(id,total_price,unitPrice,room_desc,construction_year,area,location)" \
            " values(%d,%d,%d,%s,%d,%lf,%s)"
try:
    print(cursor.description)
    cursor.execute(insert2db % (1,2,3,"room_desc",2016,2.4,"xiasha"))
    connect.commit()
except:
    connect.rollback()
    print("Failed to insert into database!")
    exit(0)
print("Insert into the database successfully!")
```

Without try-catch the error return is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/desktop/Computer/Python/web_scrapping/;project3_lianjia/exm.py", line 40, in <module>
    cursor.execute(insert2db % (1,2,3,"room_desc",2016,2.4,"xiasha"))
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 165, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 860, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1061, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1349, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1018, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 384, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\94257\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'xiasha' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Please, just stop using string formatting to make queries. This is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Quote your strings in your insert. values(%d,%d,%d,'%s',%d,%lf, '%s')

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot!